# React Native and AppHub: No bundle URL present

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm sitting here doing the quickstart on AppHub after finishing my React Native project, and when it gets to the point of trying to uncomment out these lines, I get a `No bundle URL present` error.

```
AHBuild *build = [[AppHub buildManager] currentBuild];
  jsCodeLocation = [build.bundle URLForResource:@"main"
                                  withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

How can I fix this?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [AppHub setApplicationID:@"25QLeX4o6N8Xm0naFxnx"];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  /**
   * OPTION 3 - AppHub
   *
   * Load cached code and images from AppHub.
   *
   */

  AHBuild *build = [[AppHub buildManager] currentBuild];
  jsCodeLocation = [build.bundle URLForResource:@"main"
                                  withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Hang"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is rather poor in this regards and code be more informative. When you archive the application the code will work - it just won't in `debug` mode

It does state that to uncomment the following code when deploying.

```
AHBuild *build = [[AppHub buildManager] currentBuild];
  jsCodeLocation = [build.bundle URLForResource:@"main"
                                  withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

To test this on the simulator change the schema to `release` by going to

**Product** > **Schema** > **Edit Schema** > **Change build configuration to `release`**

This is basically what an archive does.

[image]